# Problem with codebender project not compiling

Tags: programming, c++

I have written a codebender project which returns this error:

```
Oops! Looks like there was a serious issue with your project. 

If you are not sure what could be wrong please contact us

/mnt/tmp/compiler.amxHJ9/files/Many Games.o: In function `gamesMaster::gamesMaster()':
Many Games.cpp:(.text._ZN11gamesMasterC2Ev+0xa): undefined reference to `vtable for gamesMaster'
Many Games.cpp:(.text._ZN11gamesMasterC2Ev+0xc): undefined reference to `vtable for gamesMaster'
```

What does it mean by `vtable`?

The code uses basic classes and inheritance.

The program is designed to select and play the game of your choice.  I have only programmed the basic structure.

Class `games` contains a ref to the class `gamesMaster`.

Class `gamesMaster` contains a ref to `simpleTimer`.

Classes `playHiLow` and `playSimon` are children of `gamesMaster`.

Class `games` handles and input and outputs, `win` and `lose` control and keeps track of lives.

Class `gamesMaster` handles the `simpleTimer`, displays a new round, checks for the correct answer, and checks if game has finished successfully.

The `main()` function runs a routine in the `games` class.

The code is listed here: https://codebender.cc/sketch:144869

```
class simpleTimer
{
private:
    unsigned long _previousMillis;
    unsigned long _interval;

public:
    simpleTimer()
    {

    }
    void start(float mins)
    {
        _interval = (unsigned long) (mins * 60 * 1000);
        _previousMillis = millis();
    }
    bool stillRunning()
    {
        return (millis() - _previousMillis < _interval);
    }
};

class gamesMaster
{
public:
    unsigned short lives;
    gamesMaster()
    {
        timeOutTimer = new simpleTimer();
        gameTimer = new simpleTimer();
        gameTimer->start(1.5);
        lives = 5;
    }
    void right()
    {
        Serial.println("Correct");
    }
    void wrong()
    {
        Serial.println("Wrong");
    }
    void winGame()
    {
        Serial.println("**********");
        Serial.println("* WINNER *");
        Serial.println("**********");
    }
    void loseGame()
    {
        Serial.println("\\ /          \\ /");
        Serial.println(" X    LOST    X");
        Serial.println("/ \\          / \\");
    }
    void startTimeOut(float mins)
    {
        timeOutTimer->start(mins);
    }
    bool notTimedOut()
    {
        return timeOutTimer->stillRunning();
    }
    bool gameTimerOver()
    {
        return !gameTimer->stillRunning();
    }
    simpleTimer *timeOutTimer;
    simpleTimer *gameTimer;

    virtual void setupForNewRound(void);
    virtual bool checkAnswer(unsigned short);
    virtual bool reachedEnd(void);
};

class gameHiLow: public gamesMaster
{
public:
    gameHiLow() : gamesMaster() {}
    void setupForNewRound()
    {
        Serial.println("  ->(HiLow) New round");
    }
    bool checkAnswer(unsigned short answer)
    {
        Serial.println("  ->(HiLow) Correct Answer");
        return HIGH;
    }
    bool reachedEnd()
    {
        Serial.println("  ->(HiLow) End of game");
        return HIGH;
    }
};

class gameSimon: public gamesMaster
{
public:
    gameSimon() : gamesMaster() {}
    void setupForNewRound()
    {
        Serial.println("  ->(Simon) New round");
    }
    bool checkAnswer(unsigned short answer)
    {
        Serial.println("  ->(Simon) Correct Answer");
        return HIGH;
    }
    bool reachedEnd()
    {
        Serial.println("  ->(Simon) End of game");
        return HIGH;
    }
};


class games
{
private:
    unsigned short _gameToPlay;
    unsigned short _levelToPlay;
    gamesMaster *myGame;
    unsigned short _getAnswer()
    {
        if (Serial.available() > 0)
        {
            int inByte = Serial.read();
            Serial.println("  ->(games) Decode Answer");

            switch (inByte)
            {
                case '<':
                    return 1;
                    break;
                case '>':
                    return 2;
                    break;
            }

        }
        return 0;

    }
    bool _respond()
    {
        unsigned short answer;
        while(myGame->notTimedOut())
        {
            if((answer = _getAnswer()) != 0)
            {
                if(myGame->checkAnswer(answer) == HIGH) return HIGH;
            }
        }
        return LOW;
    }
public:
    games(unsigned short gameToPlay, unsigned short levelToPlay)
    {
        _gameToPlay = gameToPlay;
        _levelToPlay = levelToPlay;
        switch(_gameToPlay)
        {
            case 1:
                myGame = new gameHiLow();
                Serial.println(" ->(game) play Higher or Lower Game");
                break;
            case 2:
                myGame = new gameSimon();
                Serial.println(" ->(game) play Simon Game");
                break;
        }
    }
    void play()
    {
        unsigned short answer;
        while(!myGame->gameTimerOver())
        {
            myGame->setupForNewRound();
            myGame->startTimeOut(.5);
            if(_respond() == HIGH)
            {
                myGame->right();
                if(myGame->reachedEnd())
                {
                    myGame->winGame();
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                myGame->wrong();
                if(--myGame->lives <= 0)
                {
                    myGame->loseGame();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        myGame->loseGame();
    }
};


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
games *game;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    unsigned short gameToPlay = 1;
    unsigned short levelToPlay = 1;
    game = new games(gameToPlay, levelToPlay);
}

void loop()
{
    Serial.println("Let the games begin");
    game->play();
    Serial.println("Program Complete");
    delay(5000);
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @GeryOshlike.  But that's not the only option.

Yes, you can make them *pure virtual*:

```
virtual void setupForNewRound(void) = 0;
virtual bool checkAnswer(unsigned short) = 0;
virtual bool reachedEnd(void) = 0;
```

Or you can make them virtual with a default function:

```
virtual void setupForNewRound(void) { }
virtual bool checkAnswer(unsigned short) { return false; }
virtual bool reachedEnd(void) { return false; }
```

Pure virtual will complain when you compile if you haven't implemented those functions in your child class.  By providing a default function body it will not complain if you haven't implemented it, and will just use the default body.

If it's a function which you know will always have to be implemented at the child level (will always be different) then go the pure virtual route.  If it's a function that will be the same in a number of children but differ in only a few, then providing the default body and overriding with different ones when needed is the better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065154/undefined-reference-to-vtable

declare these functions pure virtual:

```
virtual void setupForNewRound(void) = 0;
virtual bool checkAnswer(unsigned short) = 0;
virtual bool reachedEnd(void) = 0;
```